# Passing variables to subscripts

Tags: powershell

I was wondering if this was possible.  I am trying to make a script we will refer to as a master script.  This script queries a DB to get a list of servers we will call `$svrs`.  Simple stuff.

The thing I don't know how to do or if it is possible is to run a series of subscripts from the master script using the `$srvrs.Name` variable as a parameter on those scripts.

```
$svrs = "get list sql stuff"
$scrpath = 'D:\test'

$scripts = Get-ChildItem $scrpath

$scripts.Name | ForEach-Object {
  Invoke-Expression $_ {I have no idea how to get server name variable here}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comments, you do need a nested loop which won't be too complicated.

```
$Scripts | Select-object Name | % {$curScript = $_
                                   $Servers | % {.\$_ $CurScript}
                                                }
```

Comment: If it was just one 'MyOtherScript' that would be easy.  I am trying to run a series of scripts located in a directory.  Possibly up to 30 or 40 so I think I may need a nested foreach loop?  I am just having issues formulating it.

Comment: that's easy too.. Edit coming up.

Comment: Or are you saying you want to run all the files in the folder?

Comment: Yes.  All of the files in the folder.  So I want to do a get-childitem from the folder and run it from that variable.  I will be adding and removing the scripts from that directory regularly.

Comment: I think you may need to clarify it for me. Do you want to RUN the scripts in the `$Scripts` variable or use them as parameters for other processes?

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to explain...  I want to have 2 arrays.  One is a list of servers from a db (easy).  The other is a list of scripts in a directory.  I want to run each script in that directory for every server in the server list, using the server name as a parameter.

Comment: Make sure to use the `$curscript` variable since you can't nest `$_`

Comment: Yeah I saw that.  That was the part that my brain couldn't resolve.  I'm still a neophyte.

Comment: Sorry, still not working.  The .\ is not recognized as a command.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up resolving this myself with @JNK 's assistance...

Here is how I got the result I needed.

```
$allServers | ForEach-Object {
    $currentServer = $_
    $scripts.Name | ForEach-Object {
        Invoke-Expression ".\$_ $currentServer"
        }
    }
```